# mesh is distorted due to armature

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones

I created a mesh and made it a child of an armature.
once I did that, the mesh has been distorted.
[image]
When I changed the Pole Angle to 90 deg (it was -90). the mesh was fixed but then the IK went the wrong direction..
[image]

How can I fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: I just edit the IK after rotating the bone.